# folding menu with jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I used to use this piece of code to fold and unfold the menu in my website with jquery 1.8.3 but after updating this to >1.10.2 it hides the menu automatically again. I think this is because it goes through all the code. How can I change this to work with the new update? ( sorry for my lack of javascript )

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#menu-button').toggle(function() {
        $('#menu').animate({
            marginTop: '+=10',
            height: '100%',
            opacity: 1
        }, 300, function() {
            // Animation complete.
        });
    }, function() {
        $('#menu').animate({
            marginTop: '-=10',
            opacity: 0,
            height: '0px'
        }, 300, function() {
            // Animation complete.
        });
    });

});
```

click [here](http://jsbin.com/razeguma/1/) for a working example of how it is now.

Comment: Does the menu have to fold and unfold upon mouse hover events? Then probably you should try binding hover events.

Comment: No it should fold, unfold on toggle(click) like it is now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just rewrite it with toggleClass();

Here is working jsbin : http://jsbin.com/razeguma/4/edit